# Small changes in bounds changes the curve fit for scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I need to fit a curve to data and am first testing `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` on a plot I've created myself. What's worrying is that just slightly changing the bounds affects the estimates for the curve parameters, which doesn't inspire great confidence that on real data it will correctly estimate. Why is this happening and is there an alternative to curve_fit that I can use?

The function I'm testing it on (and will eventually need to fit to data) is `y = a*(x/b)**9`. I've plotted it for `a = 0.03` and `b = 0.007` in the code below, which I then use curve_fit to estimate a and b for. If I make the bounds `0 < a < 0.1` it overestimates `a` to be `0.0429`. If I make the bounds `0 < a < 0.04` it underestimates `a` to be `0.0222`. My actual data has many powers (`d`) so I will be estimating not just for `d = 9` but a range of `d`'s. If they are all underestimates or overestimates this will have a large impact at the end. Is there a way I can fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

d = 9

def func(x,a,b):
    return a*(x/b)**d

x = np.logspace(-3.2,-2,20)

a = 0.03
b = 0.007
print(f"a = {a}, b = {b}")

y = func(x,a,b) 
plt.loglog(x,y)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y, bounds = ([0,0.005],[0.04,0.009]))
print(f'a ≈ {popt[0]}, b ≈ {popt[1]}')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show real data?

Answer (score 2):

There are an infinite number of solutions to this equation, because the a and b parameters are doing the same thing.

You can see this by taking the log of both sides of the equation and simplifying:

```
log(y) = d*log(x) - d*log(b) + log(a)
```

For example, if you have a solution a, b, then you can divide a by 1000, and divide b by the 9th root of 1000, and that is an equivalent solution.

```
a2 = a / 1000
b2 = b / (1000 ** (1/d))
y = func(x,a,b)
plt.plot(x, y)
y = func(x,a2,b2)
plt.plot(x, y)
print(f'a ≈ {a2}, b ≈ {b2}')
```

If your function has multiple equivalent fits, then curve_fit might pick any of them.